# How do I update rows with data that needs to be sorted out from several other rows in the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to update the rows of a (SQL Server 2005) table with data that is contained in another row of the same table. The problem can essentially be broken down to this:

I have an existing table that consists of columns for `ID`, `START_DATE`, `END_DATE` and some other values (that aren't really relevant for this question). The table is populated with several rows for each `ID` but with different date intervals. The `START_DATE` is a value that has been explicitly set by the client whilst the `END_DATE` is a default value coming from their system. Example:

```
ID      START_DATE      END_DATE
===================================
1       2001-01-01      2099-12-31
1       2003-01-01      2099-12-31
1       2003-03-21      2099-12-31
2       2002-11-04      2099-12-31
2       2005-08-01      2099-12-31
.       ...             ...
.       ...             ...
```

The table contains A LOT of data and now this data should be exported to an external system. Only problem is that the external system is unable to handle overlapping date intervals. Thus, my goal is to achieve the following:

```
ID      START_DATE      END_DATE
===================================
1       2001-01-01      2002-12-31
1       2003-01-01      2003-03-20
1       2003-03-21      2099-12-31
2       2002-11-04      2005-07-31
2       2005-08-01      2099-12-31
.       ...             ...
.       ...             ...
```

I have looked around at other similar questions but not yet found what I'm looking for.

**Is it possible to create a query for this?**

*BTW: This is my first ever question here so please shout out if I'm not following the DOs and DON'Ts.*

Comment: So I would do this not in sql server (because I'm much more comfortable using other languages) but it's possible. Basically you can create a cursor from SELECT id, start_date, end_date and then declare 4 variables. id1, id2, end_date1, end_date2. Then using the cursor you can loop through the result set checking if the ids are the same for your current position and the prior position of the cursor. If they are, and the dates overlap, you can set the date for the previous using DATEADD(day,-1,@end_date2)

Comment: What version of SQL-Server? This would be easier in 2012+ with the `LAG` and `LEAD` functions.

Comment: @ypercube I have edited the question and included version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms175972.aspx) and update it from following Startdate - 1 for fitting ID's

```
Declare @a Table(ID int,      START_DATE DateTime,      END_DATE datetime)

insert into @a Select 1,'20010101','20991231'
insert into @a Select 1,'20030101','20991231'
insert into @a Select 1,'20030321','20991231'
insert into @a Select 2,'20021104','20991231'
insert into @a Select 2,'20050801','20991231'


;With CTE as
(
Select *, Row_Number() Over (Partition by ID order by Start_date) as RN
from @A
)
Update CTE SET END_DATE=ISNULL((Select START_DATE-1 from CTE ci where ci.ID=CTE.ID and ci.RN=CTE.RN+1),END_DATE)




Select * from @A
```

Another way which would work on older versions of SQLServer to would be

```
Update aTable set END_DATE=ISNULL(
                              (Select Min(START_DATE)-1 from aTable ai where ai.ID=aTable.ID and ai.START_DATE>aTable.START_DATE)
                             ,END_DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query will do the desired updation. I have taken DatePeriod as Name of the table.

```
UPDATE [DatePeriod]  SET [DatePeriod].END_DATE=DpNew.NewEND_DATE
FROM [DatePeriod] Dp 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DP1.Id,DP1.START_DATE,DATEADD(day, -1,  DP2.START_DATE) NewEND_DATE 
    FROM 
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID,START_DATE  ) AS SNo,* FROM [DatePeriod] ) DP1
        INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID,START_DATE  ) AS SNo,* FROM [DatePeriod] ) DP2
        ON DP1.ID=DP2.ID AND DP1.SNo=(DP2.SNO-1) 
) DpNew ON DpNew.Id=Dp.Id and DpNew.START_DATE=DP.START_DATE
```